# Function const return type: invalid initialisation of reference of type

Tags: c++, function, reference, constants

I have this function:

```
Triangle& Triangle::get_largest_triangle(const Triangle& t) const
{
    float area_this = get_area();
    float area_other = t.get_area();

    if (area_other > area_this)
        return *this;
    else
        return t;
}
```

This doesn't work unless I declare the returned Triangle to be constant, i.e.:

```
const Triangle& Triangle::get_largest_triangle(const Triangle& t) const
```

Why is this? I'm fairly new to C++ but as far as I can tell, neither 'this', nor the object in the parameter list are being changed in the function so I don't really see what the issue is.

e.g. What if I want to change some of the values stored in the largest Triangle after running this function?

Comment: When it returns `t`, it's returning a constant to something that might not be declared constant.

Comment: What is the actual error text?  It should explain why it is complaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function returns a non-const reference to a Triangle. This means that the caller can modify the returned object. But it returns either a reference to itself (which is const due to the function declaration), or a reference to the function argument (which is also const). So the compiler won't allow it because you are making a const object non-const.

Your options are to change the function signature to return a const:

`const Triangle& Triangle::get_largest_triangle(const Triangle& t) const`

or alternatively to make the method non-const and take a non-const reference:

`Triangle& Triangle::get_largest_triangle(Triangle& t)`

Comment: Or you can provide both overloads, then if both `*this` and `t` will be modifiable your program will execute non const version and return modifiable reference, otherwise it will 'conservatively' call const overload and return reference to const which you will not be able to modify further.

Answer (score 1):

When you return `t`, you return `const Triangle&` , which is the type of `t`.
when you declare your function to return `Triangle&` you are returning different type. remember, `const` is part of the type.
`Triangle&` is not `const Triangle&`.

Just change the return type of `get_largest_triangle` to be `const Triangle&`, or change the type of `t` to be `Triangle&`. both have their cons and pros.

Answer (score 1):

Consider following use of your function

```
const Triangle t1, t2;
Triangle &t3 = t1.get_largest_triangle(t2);
```

`t3` is now modifiable but this is reference to either `t1` or `t2`. So your code can 'accidentally' drop constness of objects. If this was possible c++ type system wouldn't be safe.

Theoretically because `t1` and `t2` are const they could be allocated in non modyfiable memory and when you will try to change one of them via `t3` which you are allowed to do, program can crash.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to convert `t`, a reference to a `const Triangle`, to a reference to a modifiable `Triangle`. That would allow the caller to modify `t`, which would be a bad thing.

You need to change your return type to make it `const`.

Comment: The second suggestion will still fail compilation.

Comment: @Sergey Because of `return *this`? Fair point. Downvote seems slightly harsh.

Comment: Alan, what is the downvote for if not to induce posters to fix the answer? :)

Comment: @Sergey I find pointing out the flaw usually works just fine. But of course it's up to you how you cast your votes. Thanks for the un-downvote.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined your function being `const`, i.e. not changing the state of the object:

```
Triangle& Triangle::get_largest_triangle(const Triangle& t) const
```

The problem is that you return a non const reference:

- if your return *this, the non const reference could be used to change the object's state.
- if you return t, the non const reference could be used to modify an object which you said taht you wouldn't change.

This is why the compiler complains. Just say that you return a reference to a const to solve your issue:

```
const Triangle& Triangle::get_largest_triangle(const Triangle& t) const
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing a const reference to the method the compiler guarantees that the object won't be changed. You try to return a non-const reference of the same object, which would lead to t loosing its constness, and the compiler is preventing you from doing that.

Rethink if you're doing the right thing here. Why can't you either use a non-const reference for t, or return a const reference?